# Replace multiple characters in a string with one occurrence of char in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to repalce multiple characters `(\t, \n or \r)` in a given string to only **one** occurrence of character which is pipeline `|` :

What is required :

```
Current string : '\t \r\nFoo\t Fooo\t Dog\t Foo\t \r\n\r\n'

Desired Output : ' |Foo| Fooo| Dog| Foo| '
```

Here is what i have tried so far :

```
import re
string = '\t \r\nFoo\t Fooo\t Dog\t Foo\t \r\n\r\n'
re.sub('\r|\n|\t', '|', string)
```

Here is the output i got `'| ||Foo| Fooo| Dog| Foo| ||||'` where pipeline is duplicate here.

Comment: Why not `| |Foo| Fooo| Dog| Foo| |` why the first and last disappear ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `+` symbol in the regex to replace sequence of that chars

```
import re

string = '\t \r\nFoo\t Fooo\t Dog\t Foo\t \r\n\r\n'
res = re.sub('[\r\n\t]+', '|', string)
print(res)  # | |Foo| Fooo| Dog| Foo| |
```

Regarding your requirements, the first and last pipe have no reason to not appear, so for now I keep that

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output, you can replace the tabs and the newlines at the start and `^` at the end `$` of the string with an empty string.

Then replace all other tabs and newlines with a pipe char `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ogV5h/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vIG8q4)

```
import re

string = '\t \r\nFoo\t Fooo\t Dog\t Foo\t \r\n\r\n'
result = re.sub(
    '^[\r\n\t]+|[\r\n\t]+$|([\r\n\t]+)',
    lambda x: '|' if x.group(1) else '',
    string
)
print(result)
```

Output

`|Foo| Fooo| Dog| Foo|`

Comment: That worked as well !, saved me couple of lines of code.

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup You want to keep the existing spaces right? Else you could do `\s+` See https://regex101.com/r/hTaodo/1